# Octopress: permission denied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, octopress

From all the reviews on octopress, I am trying to install blog with octopress. But I am facing lot of issues.

I am following tutorial on : http://octopress.org/docs/setup/

I completed the setup and chose to go with Rsync for deployment as I have linode hosting.

Initially, the issue was with rake version and i solved it with bundle exec command.

But when i try to deploy, it gives error

```
## Deploying website via Rsync
abc@example.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I am entering my email password but it is giving permission denied error.

I am not getting why this is happening. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have web hosting service you can probably deploy with [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) which is brilliantly fast, syncing new and changed files through **SSH**. If your host doesn’t offer SSH access, and you’re looking for one that does, check out [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?109007).
[Deploying with Rsync »](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/rsync/)